# OpenSSH not working on windows server 2016

Tags: powershell, openssh, windows-server-2016

I have managed to install the OpenSSH on my windows server and am able to ssh from my computer. But I am facing some weird issues after ssh into the server. When I try to move around like running `cd` it works but when I try to create a file and etc it prompted me that the command is invalid.

I have used this tutorial to set up the OpenSSH on my windows server.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is powershell installed on your server?

Looks like powershell is not installed.

What I see now, you are connected with regular cmd, not with powershell.

Try to start Powershell first

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeap, it's installed. When I try to ssh into the server and fire the command from PowerShell it works actually.

Comment: Oh wait, i get what u meant! Tested, it works. Thank you. :)